# Laravel deployment HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, server

I have my project in `/var/www/html/project` on the server,

When ever i hit `example.com` shows default server page, Then i tried 
`example.com/project` i got list of my project files/folders, Then i tried `example.com/project/public` it gave me `HTTP ERROR 500` error.

Here is my `public/index.php` file :

```
<?php
  require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
  $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php'; 
  $kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
  $response = $kernel->handle(
      $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
  );
  $response->send();
  $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

My project/storage permissions are `drwxr-xrwx.  5 root root   4096 Apr 20 12:56 storage`

What am i missing ?

Comment: Where is your index.php file located on server

Answer (score 1):

Your permissions at /storage and /bootstrap/cache have to be 775 and try to change owner group to www-data if you're using apache

Answer (score 1):

Had the same exact issue and in my case the problem was the default php version (which was 5.5+) of the shared hosting service that I use.
After I changed the php version to 7+ (laravel 5.5 needs php version >= 7) everything started to work. Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

check php version 
Laravel 5.5 requires PHP >= 7.0.0

Laravel 5.6 requires PHP >= 7.1.3